# Given relatively prime positive integers $a,b>1$, how many positive integers are there which are not non-negative integer combination sum of $a,b$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $a,b>1$ be relatively prime positive integers. I know that $ab-a-b$ is the largest positive integer which can not be written as a sum of non-negative integer combination of $a,b$. My question is : can we explicitly determine how many positive integers are there which can not be written as a non-negative integer combination of $a,b$ ?

Comment: If an integer can be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ then it is a multiple of their gcd.

Comment: @B.Goddard $a, b$ are assumed to be relatively prime. Also, the linear combinations here are assumed to have _non-negative_ coefficients. That changes the problem quite a bit from the one you describe.

Comment: @Arthur: thank you for making the specifications of my problem more clear ... I would urge you to keep your comment even if the previous were to be deleted ..

Comment: @Arthur You're reading too much into my comment.  I want the OP to think in terms of lines $ax+by = 1$, $ax+by = 2$, etc.  and how those lines would intersect lattice points in the first quadrant.

Comment: @B.Goddard In that case, mentioning the gcd is a pretty large red herring, since it is relatively irrelevant. But your second comment seems like a rather reasonable approach.

Comment: The most explicit I can get is a summation. If $a\lt b$ then there are: $$\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\left\lfloor\frac{bk}{a}\right\rfloor$$ such numbers. Although you should definitely double-check this result.

Comment: Having thought a bit more I further conjecture that the result simplifies to $$\frac{1}{2}(a-1)(b-1)\, .$$

Comment: @N.Shales your conjecture is correct:
$$
\begin{align*}
R &= \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{bk}{a}  \right \rfloor\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{(a-k)b}{a} \right\rfloor  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} b+\left\lfloor \frac{-kb}{a} \right\rfloor  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} b-1-\left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor  \\
&= (a-1)(b-1) - \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor  \\
&= (a-1)(b-1) - R
\end{align*}
$$
So that $2R = (a-1)(b-1)$. The key is the equality $\lfloor (-kb)/a\rfloor = -\lfloor kb/a \rfloor - 1$ which holds when $a$ does not divide $kb$.

Comment: @YongHaoNg: Thank you! I thought this question was long buried, so I didn't expect a reply. Thank you again and (+1) for your answer :)

Comment: @N.Shales I saw it a few days ago but it took me a while before I found a not very involved solution to the floor-sum.

Comment: @YongHaoNg: It is a good proof, almost the same as for the sum of an arithmetic progression. Makes me wonder whether there is a nice way to generalise to other types of floor sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N = ab$, we count the number of integers $0\leq t \leq N$ that can be written as
$$
t = ma+nb
$$
such that $m,n\geq 0$. Let there be $R$ such numbers. Since the largest non-representable (positive)-integer is $ab-a-b$, all non-representable numbers are in $[0,N]$ and hence we know there are $N+1 - R$ of them.

If $n\geq a$, then we replace it with
$$
ma+nb = (m+b)a + (n-a)b = m'a+n'b
$$
So with repeated application we may assume that $0\leq n < a$. We require
$$
0 \leq ma+nb \leq N \implies 0 \leq ma \leq N-nb = (a-n)b
$$
Hence we get the bounds of $m$ as 
$$
0 \leq m \leq \left \lfloor \frac{(a-n)b}{a}\right \rfloor
$$
This means the number of integers we can represent for a given $n$ is
$
\left \lfloor \frac{(a-n)b}{a} \right \rfloor + 1
$. Now summing this over all possibilities $n=0,1,\dots a-1$, the number of representable integers $R$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
R = \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{(a-k)b}{a} \right\rfloor +1
&= \left\lfloor \frac{(a)b}{a} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{(a-1)b}{a} \right\rfloor + \cdots + \left\lfloor \frac{(2)b}{a} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{(1)b}{a} \right\rfloor + a\\
R &= a + b + \sum_{k=1}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor \\
\end{align*}
$$
Next we observe that if $a$ does not divide $kb$, then for some integer $t$
$$
t < \frac{kb}{a} < t+1 \Longleftrightarrow -t-1 < \frac{-kb}{a} < -t
$$
In particular this applies for $1\leq k\leq a-1$, since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a>1$. We use the inequalities to obtain 
$$
\left \lfloor \frac{-kb}{a}\right \rfloor = -t-1 = - \left \lfloor \frac{kb}{a}\right \rfloor -1,
$$
This lets us get another equation of $R$ as
$$
\begin{align*}
R = \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{(a-k)b}{a} \right\rfloor +1
&= \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{-kb}{a} \right\rfloor + b + 1 \\
&= a(b+1) + \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{-kb}{a} \right\rfloor\\
&= a(b+1) + \sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\left\lfloor \frac{-kb}{a} \right\rfloor \\
&= a(b+1) + \sum_{k=1}^{a-1}-\left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor -1\\
R &= ab + 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore adding both equations of $R$, we have
$$
2R = ab + a + b + 1 = (a+1)(b+1)
$$
giving us $R=(ab+a+b+1)/2$. Notice that $R$ is not an integer if and only if $a,b$ are both even, which is not possible since $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Finally, the number of integers considered is $ab+1$, so the number of integers not representable is
$$
ab+1 - \frac{ab+a+b+1}{2} = \frac{ab -a - b+1}{2} = \frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Proposition.** Let $a,b$ be relatively prime integers greater than $1,$ and let $m=ab-a-b.$
If $x\in\{0,1,2,\dots,m\},$ then exactly one of the two numbers $x$ and $m-x$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ with nonnegative integer coefficients.

It follows that exactly half the elements of $\{0,1,2,\dots,m\}$ can be expressed as nonnegative integral linear combinations of $a$ and $b;$ that is, there are exactly $\frac{m+1}2=\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}2$ numbers which cannot be so expressed.